# Do I need to find sum each PDF individually to find the CDF

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

The probability is 0.316 that an audit of a retail business will turn up irregularities in the collection of state sales tax. If 16 retail businesses are audited, find the probability that:

(b) at least 5 will have irregularities in the collection of state sales tax.

I know P(x>=5) = 1 - P(x<5) = 1 - CDF(4)

To find CDF, is there a straight forward formula or do I need to find PDF(4) + PDF(3) ... + PDF(0)?

(I know you can do this on a calculator, but these problems are no calculator)

Comment: Is the question presented as multiple choice, or do you have to give an exact numerical answer? If it’s multiple choice, you might be able to play some cute games with inequalities about the binomial CDF to isolate the correct choice. Otherwise, you’ll just have to do some tedious arithmetic.

Comment: @Sycorax, yeah it's open ended. Thanks, I was just wondering if I was missing something here or I actually had to go through the entire probability distribution.

Comment: It is likely you have learned about the Binomial Distribution.  What formulas do you know for its PDF?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.